# OpenCV access current and previous frame

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector, computer-vision

I need the current and previous frame for some calculations in OpenCV C++.

Here is my code so far:

```
    vector <cv::Mat> frames;
    // Current frame
    Mat M = current_frame; 
    Mat F; // previous frame
    // set Previous Frame
    if (frames.empty()) {
        F = M;
        frames.push_back(M);
        cout << "empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        F = frames.back();
        frames.push_back(M);
        cout << " NOTempty" << endl;
    }

    // print frame Mat means to see if things look okay
    cout << mean(M) << endl;
    cout << mean(F) << endl;
```

The idea is that   `M` is the current frame and `F` is the previous frame. Frames are stored in `frames`, a vector of matrices. If `frames` is empty, let `F` = `M` because there is no previous frame. Then, add `M` to `frames`. If `frames` is not empty, than `M` is the current frame and `F` is the last Mat from the vector `frames`. After `F` is extracted, the current frame `M` is added to the end of `frames`.

I am printing out the mean of `M` and `F` so that I have some easy to read reference in the terminal if it worked properly. Unfortunately, it looks not right.

This is what is printed out:

```
empty
[5.09352, 6.60551, 8.54364, 0]
[5.09352, 6.60551, 8.54364, 0]

 NOTempty
[5.02325, 6.46646, 8.39534, 0]
[92.0037, 97.9186, 106.677, 0]

 NOTempty
[4.94272, 6.38162, 8.32141, 0]
[91.7741, 97.7845, 106.555, 0]
```

It should look like this:

```
empty
[5.09352, 6.60551, 8.54364, 0]
[5.09352, 6.60551, 8.54364, 0]

 NOTempty
[5.02325, 6.46646, 8.39534, 0]
[5.09352, 6.60551, 8.54364, 0]

 NOTempty
[4.94272, 6.38162, 8.32141, 0]
[5.02325, 6.46646, 8.39534, 0]
```

This should be simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why even use the vector. you just need two variables, for previous and current frame. whenever a new frame shows up, assign `previous_frame = current_frame; current_frame = new_frame;` and check `if (previous_frame.empty() || current_frame.empty()) continue;` or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not missing a loop somewhere in that snippet? If I try something like this:

```
//create a dummy vector of mats:
std::vector<cv::Mat> sourceMats;
sourceMats.push_back( cv::Mat(1, 4, CV_32F, {1, 1, 1, 1}) );
sourceMats.push_back( cv::Mat(1, 4, CV_32F, {2, 2, 2, 2}) );
sourceMats.push_back( cv::Mat(1, 4, CV_32F, {3, 3, 3, 3}) );

//frames buffer:
std::vector <cv::Mat> frames;

//loop thru all frames:
for( int i = 0; i < (int)sourceMats.size(); i++ ){

    // Current frame
    cv::Mat M = sourceMats[i];
    cv::Mat F; // previous frame

    // set Previous Frame
    if (frames.empty()) {
        F = M;
        frames.push_back(M);
        std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        F = frames.back();
        frames.push_back(M);
        std::cout << " NOTempty" << std::endl;
    }

    // do not compute the mean, I just want to check out the FIFO contents:
    std::cout << M << std::endl;
    std::cout << F << std::endl;
}
```

I get this output (note that I removed the mean function - just to check out the raw data):

```
empty
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
NOTempty
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
NOTempty
[3, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Seems like your `FIFO` is working as expected... What did you expect from the [mean](https://cppsecrets.com/users/2194110105107104105108981049711648504964103109971051084699111109/C00-OpenCV-cvmean.php) function?